# How do I perform a bulk update with func as a value in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a database structure that looks like the following:

**Current Values**

```
| file_id | file_path   | 
+---------+-------------+
|  1      | path\test   |
+---------+-------------+
|  2      | path\test2  |
+---------+-------------+
|  2      | path\test3  |
+---------+-------------+
```

Using `sqlalchemy`, I am attempting to use `func.replace` to replace the backslashes to forward slashes in the `file_path` column.

**Desired Values**

```
| file_id | file_path   | 
+---------+-------------+
|  1      | path/test   |
+---------+-------------+
|  2      | path/test2  |
+---------+-------------+
|  3      | path/test3  |
+---------+-------------+
```

As of right now, I am updating each row individually and I am able to perform the replace without any issues

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, Integer, String, func, create_engine

table = Table('file_table', MetaData(), Column('id', Integer), Column('file_path', String))
file_ids = [1, 2, 3]

connection = create_engine('connections_string')
cursor = connection.connect()

for file_id in file_ids:
    q_ = table.update().values({'file_path': func.replace(table.c.file_path, '\\', '/')}).where(table.c.file_id == file_id)
    cursor.execute(query)

cursor.close()
```

Rather than doing each update individually, I am attempting to convert this to a bulk update. I have done bulk updates before, and the following is how I would normally perform one

```
scripts = [{'file_path': 'new_column_value', 'bk_file_id': f} for f in [1,2,3]]
q_ = table.update().where(table.c.file_id == bindparam('bk_file_id'))
cursor.execute(q_, scripts)
```

The above works as normal, but it does not works when implementing `func.replace`

```
scripts = [{'file_path': func.replace(table.c.file_path, '\\', '/'), 'bk_file_id': f} for f in [1,2,3]]
q_ = table.update().where(table.c.file_id == bindparam('bk_file_id'))
cursor.execute(q_, scripts)
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bulk_update.py", line 15, in <module>
    cursor.execute(q_,scripts)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 914, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1344, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1116, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\mysqldb.py", line 95, in do_executemany
    rowcount = cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 195, in executemany
    self.rowcount = sum(self.execute(query, arg) for arg in args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 195, in <genexpr>
    self.rowcount = sum(self.execute(query, arg) for arg in args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 164, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 143, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 123, in _escape_args
    return dict((key, conn.literal(val)) for (key, val) in args.items())
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 123, in <genexpr>
    return dict((key, conn.literal(val)) for (key, val) in args.items())
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 800, in literal
    return self.escape(obj, self.encoders)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 793, in escape
    return escape_item(obj, self.charset, mapping=mapping)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\converters.py", line 27, in escape_item
    val = encoder(val, mapping)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\converters.py", line 110, in escape_unicode
    return u"'%s'" % _escape_unicode(value)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\converters.py", line 73, in _escape_unicode
    return value.translate(_escape_table)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 738, in __getattr__
    key)
AttributeError: Neither 'Function' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'translate'
```

How can I get around this error to perform the bulk updating using `func`?

Comment: The error message references an attribute `translate` somewhere, but it does not appear in the code you've provided. Can you give us the full stack trace?

Comment: @univerio Full trackback added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that the `executemany` form of `values` does not support expressions, but for a bulk update you shouldn't be using the `executemany` form anyway.

Essentially what you were doing before was:

```
UPDATE file_table SET file_path = replace(file_path, '\\', '/') WHERE file_id = 1;
UPDATE file_table SET file_path = replace(file_path, '\\', '/') WHERE file_id = 2;
UPDATE file_table SET file_path = replace(file_path, '\\', '/') WHERE file_id = 3;
```

And you're trying to imitate the exact queries with your bulk update. Why not just run a single query instead?

```
UPDATE file_table SET file_path = replace(file_path, '\\', '/') WHERE file_id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

And the way to do that in SQLAlchemy is pretty much exactly what you were doing before:

```
table.update().values({'file_path': func.replace(table.c.file_path, '\\', '/')}).where(table.c.file_id.in_(file_ids))
```

Comment: Thanks for this information! I ended up switching to `in_` anyways, but it's good to know that expressions aren't supported in `executemany`